# how to implement pagination for checkbox group in extjs?

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, pagination

I need to Implement pagination in the checkboxgroup of Extjs since we have a huge number of data to display in the CheckboxGroup and the select all is failing/ hanging. How do we implement pagination for checkboxgroup in ExtJs6?

Answer (score 0):

ExtJs pagination is done through the Ext.data.Store. You can use a [dataview](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.view.View.html) with a checkbox template to show the elements of a store with pagination.

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dgc), you should add a store's proxy that support pagination (start/limit params).

**update:** The fiddle has been updated with the memory paginated proxy, thanks to Alexander.

Comment: [I have implemented for you a store's proxy that supports pagination](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dgc).

Comment: I am dynamically populating the checkbox group, there is no store associated to it. in that case this approach wont work?

Comment: If you use the dataview as suggested, you will just populate the store dinamically then the view is refreshed automatically.